# Unit test case not working in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, testing, automation

I tries below unit test case and it doesnt open web browser and print directly "done" message.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest


class GoogleSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    # driver = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='../Drivers/chromedriver')
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_search(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.google.com')
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("facebook")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("btnI").click()
        # driver.find_element_by_name("btnI").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        cls.driver.quit()
        cls.print("test completed")


print("done")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After defining your unittest, you have to call it. Call the test with `unittest.main()`.

```py
from selenium import webdriver import unittest


class GoogleSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='../Drivers/chromedriver')
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_search(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.google.com')
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("facebook")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("btnI").click()
        # driver.find_element_by_name("btnI").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        cls.driver.quit()
        cls.print("test completed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()  # <- runs your unittest
    print("done")
```

Comment: it works but the last statement "done" not printing